# mongoDB aggregation: group all by boolean expression

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a collection with zip codes. I want to group all records from the collection by the first letter of the city name either being a digit or not. I want to achieve something like this:

```
            {
                    "_id" : true,
                    "n" : 1234567
            },
            {
                    "_id" : false,
                    "n" : 87543
            }
```

So far, I've tried:

```
db.zips.aggregate( [
    { $project : { _id : { $substr : ["$city",0,1] } } } ,
    {$group: {_id: {$in: ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}}}
] )
```

but mongo throws error:

```
Fri Mar 14 23:01:52.566 aggregate failed: { "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$in'", "code" : 15999, "ok" : 0 } at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898
```

what can I do to group by a Boolean expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot more simply than you might think:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { "$lte": [ { $substr: ["$city", 0, 1] }, "9" ]},
        "n": { "$sum": 1 } 
    }}
])
```

The logical [**`$lte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/#exp._S_lte) operator makes a lexcial comparison of the content, which is one character (byte) and of course "9" is *less than* "A".

Can you use [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in the way you have? No you can't, and hence the error. It is a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator and therefore could **only** be used in that pipeline stage to *filter* results, and that is not what you want.

So you want a "logical" comparison, and in a lexical context the sensible operator is applied. Whatever your case, you need to use a "logical" [**comparison operator**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

In the form of **this** particular problem, the selected "comparison" is the logical choice. Change to other operators to assert different "logical comparison.

Comment: ok, nice one, but if I want to check that a particular expression is an element of a set/array? What should I do then? E.g. I want to check that something is equal "4", "e" or "+"?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz The **correct** way to ask something different from the question that you have had answered is to ask **another** question. This covers the case that you presented. Feel free to post **another** question if you have another scenario you want an answer to.

Comment: Basing on my example, you can see that I'm trying to use `$in` to get a Boolean expression. In my opinion, above is not a precise answer to my question.